# Is there anything similar to isfile() isdir() with ftp in Python?

Tags: python, ftp

Writing a script to retrieve logfiles from one server to NAS i need to determine if sth is a file or a directory.
Does anybody know a simple way to determine if an element of ftp.nlst() is a file or a directory??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584865/determine-if-a-listing-is-a-directory-or-file-in-python-over-ftp ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code from [here](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread243712.html). It will append `[F]` to directories and leave the files as it is.

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os
ftp = FTP(self.host)
listdir = self.ftp.nlst()
for i in listdir:
    if(self.ftp.sendcmd(os.path.isdir(bool(self.ftpdir + "/" + i)))):
          self.list_box_2.Append("[F] " + i)
```

Check out `os.path` and this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584865/determine-if-a-listing-is-a-directory-or-file-in-python-over-ftp) post.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,b ut iI've already tried these and errors produced.

Comment: There is no ftpdir attribute!