# Python ftp list only directories and not files

Tags: python, list, ftp, directory, cwd

I would like to list all directories on a ftp directory and then enter each of them.
The problem is that my code also list file and try to enter them as well.

1. Is there a way to get a return value from the method ftp.cwd ?
2. Is there a way to get only directory name in the first place, or there is a better way to do what I want.

Here is the code I am using now:

```
    from ftplib import FTP
    ftp = FTP('ftp.overtherainbow.com')
    ftp.login()
    for name in ftp.nlst():
        print "listing: " + name
        ftp.cwd(name)
        ftp.retrlines('LIST')
        ftp.cwd('../')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The FTP protocol doesn't have a way of distinguishing between directories and files (as for listing). I think the best bet would be either, try and fail

```
try:
    ftp.cwd(name)
except ftplib.error_perm as detail:
    print("It's probably not a directory:", detail)
```

Or otherwise you may want to parse the output from the directory listing. This will not be platform independent though, because directory listings differ from OS to OS. 
As shown [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584865/determine-if-a-listing-is-a-directory-or-file-in-python-over-ftp/585232#585232)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Python 3.3 solution (mlsd):
http://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.mlsd

ftp.nlst and ftp.dir are "Deprecated since version 3.3: use mlsd() instead."

Comment: It is not a matter of the Python version one is using, `nlst` is very much alive. `mlsd` can be used _when the FTP server supports_ [RFC 3659](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3659.html); not the case for many servers out there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit ugly, but the `ftplib` seems not very easy to use.

```
>>> x=[]
>>> ftp.dir('-d','*/',lambda L:x.append(L.split()[-1]))
>>> x
['access-logs/', 'etc/', 'mail/', 'perl/', 'proxy/', 'public_ftp/', 'public_html/', 'subversion/', 'tmp/', 'web/', 'www/']
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

```
def get_current_dir_subdirs(self):
    ret = []
    self.ftp.dir("",ret.append)
    ret = [x.split()[-1] for x in ret if x.startswith("d")]
    return ret
```